# Should I really have all these "this." inside my class for all variables?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, this

I'm practicing OOP in JavaScript, so I've written this custom Stopwatch class that appears to work correctly. I can create new stopwatches (e.g. let sw = new Stopwatch();) then both sw.start() and sw.stop() it. While checking the time passed both before and after it has been called using sw.duration().

(1) However, I ended up adding `this.` in-front of every variable, which is quite ugly and seems superfluous - but I couldn't get it to work otherwise. So I'm wondering if I'm doing it all wrong - or is this the best way?

(2) I also don't have a constructor(). Should I have one?

(3) Would it be advised to change my duration() from a function to a property somehow, or to rename it to getDuration? What's the best-practice here?

```
class Stopwatch {
  start() {
    if (this.isRunning) throw new Error("Already running!");

    this.isRunning = true;
    this.startTime = new Date();
    console.log("Started...");
  }

  stop() {
    if (!this.isRunning) throw new Error("Not running!");

    this.isRunning = false;
    this.stopTime = new Date();
    console.log(`Stopped after ${this.duration()} seconds.`);
  }

  duration() {
    if (!this.startTime) throw new Error("Not yet started.");

    if (!this.isRunning) {
      // Stopwatch has been stopped
      this.timeDiff = (this.stopTime - this.startTime) / 1000;
    } else {
      // Stopwatch is still running
      this.timeDiff = (new Date() - this.startTime) / 1000;
    }

    return this.timeDiff;
  }
}

// Let's test a Stopwatch...
let sw = new Stopwatch();

// sw.start();
// sw.duration();
// sw.stop();
```

**Update:** Thanks for all the great replied/comments! For reference, here is my updated code with the suggestions implemented.

```
class Stopwatch {
  constructor() {
    this.isRunning = false;
    this.startTime = null;
    this.stopTime = null;
  }

  start() {
    if (this.isRunning) throw new Error("Already running!");

    this.isRunning = true;
    this.startTime = new Date();
    console.log("Started...");
  }

  stop() {
    if (!this.isRunning) throw new Error("Not running!");

    this.isRunning = false;
    this.stopTime = new Date();
    console.log(`Stopped after ${this.duration} seconds.`);
  }

  get duration() {
    if (!this.startTime) throw new Error("Not yet started.");

    let timeDiff = null;

    if (!this.isRunning) {
      // Stopwatch has been stopped
      timeDiff = (this.stopTime - this.startTime) / 1000;
    } else {
      // Stopwatch is still running
      timeDiff = (new Date() - this.startTime) / 1000;
    }

    return timeDiff;
  }
}

// Let's test a Stopwatch...
let sw = new Stopwatch();

// sw.start();
// sw.duration();
// sw.stop();
```

Comment: If you want those "variables" to be *instance properties* of the object: yes, you need `this` for them. You can also have function-local variables in addition if that makes sense, but they'll only persist for that one function call, as function-local variables do. `timeDiff` is probably a candidate for such use.

Comment: Never had a problem with `this` but can you spread the `this` operator so it appears tidier? Something like so:

`const [timeDiff, isRunning, ....] = this;`

Comment: You don't need it for `timeDiff` because you only use that in the `duration()` function so you can keep the variable in the functions scope.

Comment: Instance properties and variables are two completely separate things. So, you have to specify them. This is unlike, for example, Java or C# where `foo` will reference `this.foo`. This is because fundamentally the approach to OO in JS is not the same, so making the same inference as Java/C# will be very confusing and very error prone - the value of `this` is only determined at call time and there is no checks to ensure that `foo` is even on `this` when you use it. And if you have a variable `foo` somewhere in the scope chain it's going to be ambiguous which one to pick.

Comment: "*I also don't have a constructor(). Should I have one?*" - yes, you should initialise your instance properties in the constructor (`this.isRunning = false; this.startTime = null; this.stopTime = null;`).

Comment: "*Would it be advised to change my duration() from a function to a property somehow*" - you can use `get duration() { … }` to make it a getter property that can be used like `console.log(sw.duration)`. However, a `.getDuration()` method would be fine as well.